# CRM dataimport via Kingswaysoft for Customer Datatype

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, kingswaysoft

I'm trying to insert the data into Dynamics 365 using Kingswaysoft tool for nfp_InstrumentOfPayment entity , one of the field is nfp_donor which is of Customer datatype. My input CSV file contains fields Donor and DonorTypeID with values 'XXX XXXXXX', and 'contact' mapping to nfp_donor and nfp_donoridtype.

[image]

i think i'm not mapping the way the way Customer datatype needs to be.

[image]

The error presented is :

> Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "System.Exception: An exception has occurred when processing the input value of 'nfp_donor' field: Error: Failed to set field 'nfp_donor' value to 'XXX XXXXXX' for entity 'nfp_instrumentofpayment' (field type: Customer, value type: String). KingswaySoft.IntegrationToolkit.DynamicsCrm.CrmServiceException: CRM service call returned an error: An error has occurred when retrieving metadata for CRM entity 'Contact': CRM service call returned an error: Could not find an entity with name Contact and id 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 (784971891). (Error Code: -2147220969, Detail Message: Could not find an entity with name Contact and id 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 (784971891).) (Error Code: -2147220969, Detail Message: Could not find an entity with name Contact and id 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 (784971891).) (SSIS Integration Toolkit for Microsoft Dynamics 365, v20.1.1.2391 - DtsDebugHost, v14.0.3002.1026)KingswaySoft.IntegrationToolkit.DynamicsCrm.CrmServiceException

> : CRM service call returned an error: Could not find an entity with name Contact and id 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 (784971891). (Error Code: -2147220969, Detail Message: Could not find an entity with name Contact and id 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 (784971891).)System.ServiceModel.FaultException<KingswaySoft.DynamicsCrmServices.Soap2011.OrganizationService.OrganizationServiceFault>

Answer (score 1):

Could you verify whether you have provided the right value for nfp_donortype" field? It looks like you may have provided "Contact" but it may require all in lower case. Could you try providing "contact" instead and see if that helps? You can also reach out to our [Support team](https://www.kingswaysoft.com/about-us/contact-us) directly if you continue to face issues.

Comment: Hi, I have provided the value in lower case considering the schema names are in lower case. But no luck yet.

Comment: Reach out to our Support team as mentioned earlier as the team will be able to review the situation in detail.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. Thanks for your inputs. I was able to solve it without reaching support. i was not aware of a field named nfp_donortype, that triggered the idea. TA

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved the issue. We are just an email away if you ever need additional support.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to tell CRM in which entity to have a lookup as customer datatype refers to both Accounts and Contacts.

DonorTypeID = 1 => accounts and DonorTypeID = 2 => contacts

Ideally, providing schema name or numeric value should be the same(read about this somewhere online). But, for me numeric values worked.